# Jenkins installation in Ubuntu 22.04 with bash script using in terraform gets stuck

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I am trying to automate my jenkins installation in AWS EC2 server using bash script in my terraform infrastructure as code, the instllation halts where in ubuntu OS we have to enter in the "OK" [image]

If I run the script directly in an EC2 server I get the following screen showing
" Newer kernel available                                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ The currently running kernel version is 6.2.0-1017-aws which is not the expected kernel version  │
│ 6.2.0-1018-aws.                                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should    │
│ consider rebooting.
"
attached is the screenshot.[image]

Then in the next screen it asks for "Which services should be restarted?  "

attached is the screenshot [image]

Attached is the code for bashscript.

**install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
#echo -e '\t'   # Tab
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre -y
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
#echo -e '\t'   # Tab
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null 
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install jenkins -y
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
#echo -e '\t'   # Tab
#echo -e '\n'   # Enter
sudo systemctl enable jenkins
sudo systemctl start jenkins
sudo systemctl status jenkins
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

and the code for terraform script

**ec2.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.33"
    }
  }
}

# configured aws provider with proper credentials
provider "aws" {
  region    = "us-west-2"
  profile   = "default"
}


# create default vpc if one does not exit
resource "aws_default_vpc" "default_vpc" {

  tags    = {
    Name  = "default vpc"
  }
}


# use data source to get all avalablility zones in region
data "aws_availability_zones" "available_zones" {}


# create default subnet if one does not exit
resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_az1" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[0]

  tags   = {
    Name = "default subnet"
  }
}


# create security group for the ec2 instance
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_security_group" {
  name        = "ec2 security group"
  description = "allow access on ports 80 and 22"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default_vpc.id

  # allow access on port 8080
  ingress {
    description      = "http access"
    from_port        = 8080
    to_port          = 8080
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description      = "ssh access"
    from_port        = 22
    to_port          = 22
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = -1
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags   = {
    Name = "jenkins server security group"
  }
}


# use data source to get a registered ubuntu ami
#data "aws_ami" "ubuntu_22_04" {
#  most_recent = true
#  filter {
#    name   = "name"
#    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-amd64-*"]  # Match Ubuntu 22.04 AMIs
#  }
#  filter {
#    name   = "virtualization-type"
#    values = ["hvm"]  # Filter for HVM AMIs
#  }
#  owners = ["099720109477"]
#}

# launch the ec2 instance and install website
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
#  ami                    = data.aws_ami.ubuntu_22_04.id
  ami                    = "ami-008fe2fc65df48dac"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id              = aws_default_subnet.default_az1.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_security_group.id]
  key_name               = "bastion_key"
  #user_data              = 

  tags = {
    Name = "Jenkins server"
  }
}

# an empty resource block
resource "null_resource" "name" {

  # ssh into the ec2 instance 
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("~/bastion_key.pem")
    host        = aws_instance.ec2_instance.public_ip
  }

  # copy the install_jenkins.sh file from your computer to the ec2 instance 
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "jenkins_install.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/jenkins_install.sh"
  }

  # set permissions and run the install_jenkins.sh file
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo chmod +x /tmp/jenkins_install.sh",
      "sh /tmp/jenkins_install.sh",
    ]
  }

  # wait for ec2 to be created
  depends_on = [aws_instance.ec2_instance]
}


# print the url of the jenkins server
output "website_url" {
  value     = join ("", ["http://", aws_instance.ec2_instance.public_dns, ":", "8080"])
}
```

I was expecting the code to run and install Jenkins in the AWS ec2 server with full automation.

I am running my code in a bastion host that is in the same region of EC2 server.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're experiencing is https://learnubuntu.com/pending-kernel-upgrade/.

It comes from the [`needrestart`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/needrestart.1.html) package. One way to disable this warning is documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/743707/how-to-disable-the-newer-kernel-warning-in-debian-jessie):

> To disable this you can create a file called `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/silence_kernel.conf` with the line `$nrconf{kernelhints} = 0`;

In the context of doing this with `terraform`, a duplicate question was asked here, also for Ubuntu: [ubuntu update with terraform fails because input is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479646/ubuntu-update-with-terraform-fails-because-input-is-required)